# Is there a Suppression List import log in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, suppressionlist

I have a Suppression List in Marketing Cloud which appears to be populated by itself, some of the Unsubscribe Reasons list "Unsubscribed from the Subscription Centre" so it appears as though its somehow directly linked to the Subscription Centre.

Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

For each of the different list types, Standard (Lists), Publication Lists, and Suppression Lists, there is an option in **Properties** labeled *Public*, which has a checkbox beside it.

[image]

If the checkbox is enabled, that list will appear on the subscription center for the subscriber to update. Typically this would be a publication list or regular list, so you may want to make your suppression list hidden to public.

Comment: Thanks for providing this info, I wasn't aware this is even an option. If the Public checkbox is not marked (which in my case it is not), how else would they have got into this list?